# How to get collections inside array in Laravel or PHP

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I am passing below data through API in postman.

I want to access these values from collection inside array for Items.

```
{
    "user":"abc",
    "supplier":"xyz",
    "pdate":"1",
    "items":[
        {
            "product":"Apple",
            "qty":"1",
            "rate":"40",
            "amount":"40"
        },
        {
            "product":"Banana",
            "qty":"6",
            "rate":"4",
            "amount":"24"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: try toArray() function

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that you want to conver the items into Collection? If that's the case, you can do:

```
$data = json_decode('{ "user":"abc", "supplier":"xyz", "pdate":"1", "items":[ { "product":"Apple", "qty":"1", "rate":"40", "amount":"40" }, { "product":"Banana", "qty":"6", "rate":"4", "amount":"24" } ] }', true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

$items = collect($data['items']);
dd($items);
```

This will output:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1545
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "product" => "Apple"
      "qty" => "1"
      "rate" => "40"
      "amount" => "40"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [
      "product" => "Banana"
      "qty" => "6"
      "rate" => "4"
      "amount" => "24"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Please note, I have just added and json_decoded the data, for the sake of the example, but just do this in your controller where the data is passed in.